# Are there identity guidelines for ROS and its logos?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The point cloud library has a nice set of guidelines for conveying a standard logo and design language for identifying PCL. Does ROS have an equivalent set of logos/design documents?
See [here](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/) and [here](http://dev.pointclouds.org/attachments/download/154/pcl_identity_guidelines.pdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11100/are-there-identity-guidelines-for-ros-and-its-logos?/) by [cmansley](https://answers.ros.org/users/803/cmansley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2011-09-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/artwork

and

Here: http://www.ros.org/press-kit/

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does not have a logo identity guideline package (yet).  I helped with the PCL guideline package but haven't had time to create one for ROS.

Separate from logo identity guidelines is approval for use.  We request that companies wishing to use the ROS logo on product materials e-mail comm@willowgarage.com for review -- hopefully we can come up with more clear guidelines (ala [OSI](http://www.opensource.org/trademark-guidelines)).  As you can see from the OSI guidelines, coming up with a that document will take a little work, but as you can see, most of it boils down to common sense.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-04-24**:
Has there been any additional thoughts on setting up some identity guidelines?. I was wondering about the name of the ROS logo font, and could not find anything.